# Filtrar pares em uma tupla no Python

Tags: python, tupla

"Faça uma função chamada filtra_pares que receba uma tupla com quatro elementos inteiros como parâmetro, e retorne uma nova tupla contendo
apenas os elementos pares da tupla original, na mesma ordem em que se
encontravam."

Eu tentei fazer algo do tipo.

```
def pares(a,b,c,d):
    nova =()
    if a%2==0 and b%2 ==0 and c%2 ==0 and d%2 == 0:
            novafiltrada = nova+a,b,c,d
            return novafiltrada
```

Porém da `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

O que você está fazendo na primeira linha de código, é pedir *4 elementos*, e não **uma tupla com quatro elementos.**

```
def filtra_pares(t):
    lista = [] # Aqui se declara uma lista, pois iremos modificá-la no loop, cosia que a tupla não nos permite.
    if type(t) == tuple and len(t) == 4:
        #Se o parâmetro enviado para função, for uma tupla de quatro itens, o procedimento será feito.
         #Senão, um aviso será exibido.
        for i in t:
            #Aqui faremos um loop para cada item na tupla, caso ele não for inteiro um aviso será dado, e aquela lista inicial será limpa, para que quando o loop for parado pelo break, o resultado estar vazio.
            if type(i) != int:
                lista = []
                print('Todos os itens da tuplas devem ser inteiros.')
                break
             elif i%2 == 0:
                 #Se ele for inteiro e par, será adicionado à lista.
                 lista.append(i)
        print(tuple(lista)) #A lista é transformada em tupla e o resultado é exibido quando o loop acabar.
    else:
        print('Apenas será aceito, uma tupla, com quatro itens.')



tupla_inserida = (1,4,2,3)
filtra_pares(tupla_inserida)
#Retorno: (4,2)
```

O loop mantém a ordem dos elementos, então não precisamos nos preocupar com isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu tambem cheguei a uma solução parecieda, mas nao tinha reparado no que eu estava errado" é pedir 4 elementos, e não uma tupla com quatro elementos."
Realmente nao prestei atenção nisso, muito obrigado.